# pyzmq on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, zeromq

Has anyone managed to deploy the Python ZeroMQ bindings on a vanilla AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance?  Specifically I am using 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.2.0 running Python 3.4

In my requirements.txt I have pyzmq listed - however when I deploy to AWS, the logs show that the deployment is attempting first to link against an installed libzmq (there isn't one in the standard AMI image)  and then once that fails, it will try to compile libzmq from scratch which fails at a step using using cc1plus which fails (I assume) as g++ is also not part of the standard AMI image.

So my question is, how do I get either libzmq or g++ to be installed on my EC2 instance on deployment?

I read somewhere you can make a .ebextensions folder inside your deployment and inside there put a "configuration file" which I attempted to do with

```
 packages:
     yum:
        g++: []
```

However this changes nothing.  However I am guessing at what to name the configuration file in that folder e.g. test.config

Or am I going about this wrong and I need to instead fiddle with the instance installing stuff like this myself and then create a custom AMI image?